# How can a pip-installed module import a module at the working directory?

Tags: import, pip, working-directory

I've got a module that is installed by pip (at directories `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/`). This module imports a configuration module (`my_configuration.py`) that the user creates at the working directory:

```
try:
    import my_configuration
except:
    print("no configuration found")
    sys.exit()
```

Now, when the module is at the working directory, it is able to import this configuration module just fine, but when I try to use it from its pip-installed location, it cannot find the module at the working directory.

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but what's going wrong and how get/should I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Python lookups modules and packages to import using [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.path). Prepend your "working directory" to import modules from it.

Comment: Does it help, no?